# AngularJS multiple directives on same element, $compile:multidir ERROR

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CzcVzKSvpKJTuTKARVJz?p=preview

and this is my simple code:

```
.directive('ngB', [function () {
    return {
      'restrict': 'A',
      'scope': {
        'ngB': '='
      },
      'link': function($scope, el) {

        var clss = 'b'
          , go = function () {

            if ($scope.ngB) {

              el.removeClass('a');
              el.addClass(clss);
            } else {
              el.removeClass(clss);
            }
          };

        $scope.$watch('ngB', function () {
          go();
        });
      }
    };
  }])
  .directive('ngF', [function () {
    return {
      'restrict': 'A',
      'scope': {
        'ngF': '='
      },
      'link': function($scope, el) {

        var clss = 'f'
          , go = function () {
            if ($scope.ngF) {

              el.removeClass('a');
              el.addClass(clss);
            } else {
              el.removeClass(clss);
            }
          };

        $scope.$watch('ngF', function () {
          go();
        });
      }
    };
  }]);


  //view.html
  <span ng-b="2 > 1" ng-a="1 > 2">here</span>
```

It returns this error in console: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir

How can i fix this without removing one of the directives from the elmeent

thank you a lot.

Comment: can you please reproduce it plunkr? http://plnkr.co/edit/wGhqCyzsxwHpKnANr33n?p=preview . seems ok to me

Comment: why wouldn't you just use `ng-class` instead of creating 2 extra directives that basically do the same thing

Comment: many times it occurs when you use `ngModel` as a controller in `require`

Comment: @charlietfl don't mind this is just an example the real(long) directive does more in go()

Comment: @pankajparkar ok let me try reproducing :)

Comment: well if that's the case an oversimplification isn't going to replicate the problem. Still don't know why you don't use ng-class though

Comment: @pankajparkar http://plnkr.co/edit/CzcVzKSvpKJTuTKARVJz?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl  the oversimplifaction is producing the same error anyway, you can see on the plunkr i posted

Comment: why you don't try these directives nested each other instead of placing them on same element?

Comment: @pankajparkar sometimes, for some reasons, is not possible and you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, you cannot have two directives creating multiple scopes, whether isolate or child, on the same element.

You don't always need an isolate scope.

if all you are doing is observing a **change in an attribute value**:

```
<span ng-f="{{1 < foo}}"></span>
```

Then you could pick up the changes with `attrs.$observe`:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  attrs.$observe("ngF", function(v){
     // do something
  });
}
```

If, however, you are watching for a **change in the model value** assigned to the attribute or an expression result

```
<span ng-f="foo"></span>
<span ng-f="foo === 10"></span>
```

which seems to me to be the case, you can use `$parse` service and $watch for changes in the value.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
   var parsed = $parse(attrs.ngF);
   scope.$watch(function(){
      return parsed(scope);
   },
   function(v){
     // do something
   });
}
```

Comment: hi, appreciated your answer, i don't want to use {{}} so the second option looks great to me, just listening to the entire scope will be too heavy don't you think? ... how can i do...mmm

Comment: @sbaaaang, what do you mean by "listening to the entire scope"?

Answer (score 1):

As per angular Design [**you can't have an two isolated scope directive**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485848/why-cant-multiple-directives-ask-for-an-isolated-scope-on-the-same-element) applied on the same `DOM` element ([**Reference Link**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2729-don-t-blindly-isolate-all-the-scopes-in-angularjs-directives.htm)) ()

If you look at the AngularJS documentation, you'll see that they do recommend using isolate scopes in certain situations:

> Best Practice: Use the scope option to create isolate scopes when
>   making components that you want to reuse throughout your app.

I would prefer you to use transclusion or place directive in nested manner, in that way it would work

**HTML**

```
<span ng-b="2 > 1">Outside
   <span ng-a="1 > 2">Inside
</span>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1IOwQI2j5oiuhJP3zXEM?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: i am searching for a fix

Comment: check I updated answer with plunkr @sbaaaang this is what fix which I believe, did you visited the link which i gave in answer?

Comment: man this i already know, i am searching a fix for my specific use case, i know that nesting them will work... :)

Comment: @sbaaaang Simply you can't do it, I don't have other better option, I'm eager to get better answer on it. :) Do check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485848/why-cant-multiple-directives-ask-for-an-isolated-scope-on-the-same-element

Comment: let's see if someone more experienced, imho it is possible, but i don't know how to change it for :(

Comment: @sbaaaang probably i may missed something, Lets hope it has some fixed. :) I'm also curious to know better solution for it..

Comment: @sbaaaang If it does helped you then do up-vote, thanks in advance :) Accepted answer is not that good way that you were searching yesterday, Am i right?

Comment: upvoted, sorry for delay, the accepted answer is the only way possible for me ;)