# Wrapping a directive with a directive vs multidir error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is the code for a datepicker component i use, repeatedly, on my app. It's quite verbose, and barely anything changes from one to another. And so, i thought of making a directive to greatly shorten the code. However, i keep getting multi dir error. I don't think removing the isolated scope is a option, but surely there must be a way?

Wrapper diractive

```
app.directive('ddp', function () {
    return {
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        format: '=',
    },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'App/Main/templates/defaultDatepicker.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            if ($scope.format == null)
               $scope.format = 'dd/MM/yy';
        }
    }
});
```

Directive/code to be wrapped (defaultDatepicker.html)

```
<p class="input-group input-group-sm">
<input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="ngModel" is-open="isOpen" close-text="Fechar" clear-text="Limpar" current-text="Hoje" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isOpen=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
</p>
```

Usage

```
<div ng-controller="acid.views.curve.new as vm">
    <ddp ng-model="vm.startDate"></ddp>
</div>
```

Comment: you should close the `p` tag at end of the element..

Comment: Copy paste error, sorry about that

Comment: show us how you use it please

Comment: In the end the code was fine, it does not proc multidir. The problem was in another section of the html (some confusion with copy pasting).

Answer (score 1):

After trying out the code you provided, I don't see any "multidir" error; I just see this error instead:

> Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'ddp' is non-assignable!

Is that the error you're talking about? If so, it's because Angular is expecting your `<ddp>` element (in Usage) to have a `format` attribute with the variable to bind to. You can make the `format` binding optional by adding a question mark `?` after the `=` in the directive definition:

```
...
scope: {
    ngModel: '=',
    format: '=?',  // the '?' makes it optional
},
...
```

For more info, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=ddp .

On the other hand, if you're really getting a [multidir error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir), I don't think there's any way around it other than removing the isolate scope from your directive. However, even without an isolate scope, you can still observe changes to your attribute values. This answer might be helpful for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28889248/5249519 .

Hope that helps.